# Kivy change font color for a part in Textinput

Tags: python, colors, kivy, textinput, tagging

I have a button. It should change the text in a TextInput which was marked by the cursor from froreground_colour = [1,1,1,1] to sth. else. I tried CodeInput but it seems to highlight text following a syntax similar to a code editor which isn't quite what I want. Thank you in advance!

Ps: I use the .kv files

```css
    def colour(self):
        changecolourtext= self.screen.ids.input.selection_text
        self.screen.ids.input.cut()
        self.screen.ids.input.insert_text('[b]'+changecolourtext+'[/b]')
```